# Delphi ReadStreamStr, WriteStreamStr implementation check

Tags: delphi, stream

I'm using these implementations that I found on another post on SO. But when reading a string in sometimes, ReadStreamStr puts in extra characters into the string. So I'm posting my implementation here to have it checked and approved, and if there is a fault, corrected.

```
function ReadStreamStr(Stream: TStream): string;
{ returns a string from the stream }
var
  LenStr: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  { get length of string }
  LenStr := ReadStreamInt(Stream);
  { set string to get memory }
  SetLength(Result, LenStr);
  { read characters }
  Stream.Read(Result[1], LenStr);
end;

procedure WriteStreamStr(Stream: TStream; Str: string);
{ writes a string to the stream }
var
  StrLen: Integer;
begin
  { get length of string }
  StrLen := ByteLength(Str);
  { write length of string }
  WriteStreamInt(Stream, StrLen);
  if StrLen > 0 then
    { write characters }
    Stream.Write(Str[1], StrLen);
end;
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would personally use a pseudo-code [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/RbHpFpaP).

Comment: @TLama: There's something wrong with that code as well. its not working for me. Its reading beyond the end of the string. Using: Delphi XE2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Integer` that is written in front of the characters is the **number of bytes**, but `ReadStreamStr()` is interpreting it as the **number of characters** instead.  In D2007 and earlier, where `string` is Ansi, that works fine.  But in D2009 and later, where `string` is Unicode, that does not work.  Assuming you are using D2009+, that means `ReadStreamStr()` is allocating twice as much memory as it should be, but only filling in half of it, leave the other half uninitialized.  You are not taking `SizeOf(Char)` into account when reading (but `ByteLength()` does when writing).

Try this:

```
function ReadStreamStr(Stream: TStream): string;
{ returns a string from the stream }
var
  LenStr: Integer;
  LeftOver: array[0..SizeOf(Char)-1] of Byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  { get length of string }
  LenStr := ReadStreamInt(Stream);
  { set string to get memory }
  SetLength(Result, LenStr div SizeOf(Char));
  if LenStr > 0 then begin
    { read characters }
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Result[1], LenStr);
    { just in case the length was not even }
    LenStr := LenStr mod SizeOf(Char);
    if LenStr > 0 then
      Stream.ReadBuffer(LeftOver[0], LenStr);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function ReadStreamStr(Stream: TStream): string;
{ returns a string from the stream }
var
  LenStr: Integer;
  Buf: TBytes;
begin
  Result := '';
  { get length of string }
  LenStr := ReadStreamInt(Stream);
  if LenStr > 0 then begin
    { get memory }
    SetLength(Buf, LenStr);
    { read characters }
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Buf[1], LenStr);
    { convert to string }
    Result := TEncoding.Unicode.GetString(Buf);
  end;
end;
```

Either way, keep in mind that if the stream data was written in D2007 or earlier, but is read in D2009 or later, then this code will not work as-is.  You would have to go the `TBytes` approach, but use a more appropriate `TEncoding` for the decoding, such as `TEncoding.Default`.

Personally, I would have opted to instead read/write the strings as UTF-8 from the beginning:

```
function ReadStreamStr(Stream: TStream): UTF8String;
{ returns a string from the stream }
var
  LenStr: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  { get length of string }
  LenStr := ReadStreamInt(Stream);
  { set string to get memory }
  SetLength(Result, LenStr);
  if LenStr > 0 then
    { read characters }
    Stream.Read(PAnsiChar(Result)^, LenStr);
end;

procedure WriteStreamStr(Stream: TStream; const Str: UTF8tring);
{ writes a string to the stream }
var
  StrLen: Integer;
begin
  { get length of string }
  StrLen := Length(Str);
  { write length of string }
  WriteStreamInt(Stream, StrLen);
  if StrLen > 0 then
    { write characters }
    Stream.Write(PAnsiChar(Str)^, StrLen);
end;
```